# Console log in Reduce() returning NaN

Tags: javascript, reduce

This function sums the lengths of all array elements and it works by returning the final value, but using console.log returns the length of the first element and NaN for the rest. Why?

```js
function test(s) {
  return s.split(' ').reduce((a, b) => {
      console.log(a + b.length)
    }, 0);
}

console.log(test("aa aaa aaaa"));
```

Comment: btw `'aa aaa aaaa'.length` works as well

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A Since OP's function basically counts non-space character, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your issue

`a` will always have the value that is returned from the previous iteration or the initial value `0`. Therefore in the first iteration it is `0 + b.length` which results in `2`. But then you don't return anything, therefore the return type is `undefined`. Therefore in the second iteration you have `undefined + 2` which results in `NaN` and that for every other iteration. As you also don't return anything in the last iteration, the return type in the last iteration is `undefined` and your `console.log()` at the end will print `undefined`.

### The solution

You need to `return` the value so it is used for the next iteration.

```js
function test(s) {
  return s.split(' ').reduce((a, b) => {
      return a + b.length
    }, 0);
}

console.log(test("aa aaa aaaa"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also remove the curly braces for a more concise syntax:

```js
function test(s) {
  return s.split(' ').reduce((a, b) => a + b.length, 0);
}

console.log(test("aa aaa aaaa"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, so there's no way to console log it to see what is actually happening? I tried to console log a and b.length separately to get a visual but I was wondering why logging the operation directly doesn't work

Comment: I've added an explanation, that will hopefully make it clear to you. It does log the correct results.

Comment: Oh so it's absolutely necessary to return something at every iteration in order to see the result? I was under the impression we could console log it as a regular accumulator, sort of like ````console.log(acc += num)```` when summing numbers in an array for example

Comment: Yes, your accumulater will always be the return value of the previous iteration or the intitial value in the first iteration. So yes it is necessary to return something in every iteration to get the accumulator set correctly. You can still `console.log(acc += num)` as long as you then `return acc` at the end of the callback.